# scanning file than replacing numbers in array, java

Tags: java, arrays, filereader

Is it possible to read a line from an txt file into an int array then scan this array and replace numbers from each slot of it? I need it because I made a 100x300 map in tiled (a tile map editor) but I can't change the indexes and I need specific ones for my code to make a map out of it.

Example:

The line from the original file looks like this

1 1 1 1 1 --> safe in int array --> scan through every element in the array and replace for example "1" to "2".

I tried it and I only came to reading the file in the program but I got troubles replacing the elements in the array.

```
            try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        try {
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] values = line.split(",");
                
                int size = values.length;
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    
                    String x = values[i];
                    int y = Integer.parseInt(x);
                    System.out.println(y);
                    replace(y); //method for replacing bc its a lot of numbers i want to replace
                    System.out.println("replaced: " + y);
                    String z =  Integer.toString(y);
                    values[i] = z;
                    out.write(values[i] + " ");
                }
            }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
        out.close();

    }

My replace method looks like this:

    private static void replace(int i) {

    
    if(i == 0) {
        i = 14;
    }
    if(i == 1) {
        i = 15;
    }
    if(i == 2) {
        i = 16;
    }
    if(i == 3) {
        i = 22;
    }
    if(i == 4) {
        i = 20;
    }
    if(i == 5) {
        i = 23;
    }
    if(i == 6) {
        i = 40;
    }
    if(i == 7) {
        i = 13;
    }
    if(i == 8) {
        i = 17;
    }
    if(i == 9) {
        i = 12;
    }
    if(i == 10) {
        i = 18;
    }
    if(i == 11) {
        i = 18;
    }
    if(i == 12) {
        i = 10;
    }
    if(i == 13) {
        i = 17;
    }
    if(i == 14) {
        i = 41;
    }
    if(i == 16) {
        i = 19;
    }
    if(i == 17) {
        i = 20;
    }
    if(i == 18) {
        i = 21;
    }
    if(i == 19) {
        i = 24;
    }
    if(i == 20) {
        i = 15;
    }
    if(i == 21) {
        i = 25;
    }
    if(i == 22) {
        i = 39;
    }
    if(i == 23) {
        i = 27;
    }
    if(i == 24) {
        i = 27;
    }
    if(i == 25) {
        i = 28;
    }
    if(i == 26) {
        i = 29;
    }
    if(i == 27) {
        i = 35;
    }
    if(i == 28) {
        i = 33;
    }
    if(i == 29) {
        i = 36;
    }
    if(i == 30) {
        i = 11;
    }
    if(i == 31) {
        i = 30;
    }
    if(i == 32) {
        i = 30;
    }
    if(i == 33) {
        i = 10;
    }
    if(i == 34) {
        i = 31;
    }
    if(i == 35) {
        i = 31;
    }
    if(i == 36) {
        i = 26;
    }
    if(i == 37) {
        i = 30;
    }
    if(i == 38) {
        i = 13;
    }
    if(i == 40) {
        i = 32;
    }
    if(i == 41) {
        i = 33;
    }
    if(i == 42) {
        i = 34;
    }
    if(i == 43) {
        i = 37;
    }
    if(i == 44) {
        i = 28;
    }
    if(i == 45) {
        i = 38;
    }
}
```

^ And this for every number I want to replace.

Comment: You are not replacing anything in text, you are just replacing variable y from 1 to 0. Could you edit your question with replace method body?

Comment: @mihajlo I don't really understand what you mean, but I added my replace method in the question.

Comment: You do realize you aren't returning a value from the replace method, right? i.e. `return y;` from `replace(y)` so that you can reasign the new value such that `y = replace(y);`.

Comment: @Sherif Ah yes thanks, I also replaced all the if´s with else if, does that make sense?

Comment: Om my god I got it thanks!°!!